# Page-level execution of JavaScript when serving concatenated files

Tags: javascript

#### Scenario:

A web site with *x* number of pages is being served with a **single, concatenated JavaScript file**. Some of the individual JavaScript files pertain to a page, others to plugins/extensions etc.

When a page is served, the entire set of JavaScript is executed (as execution is performed when loaded). Unfortunately, **only a sub-section of the JavaScript** pertains directly to the page. The rest is relevant to other pages on the site, **and may have potential side-effects on the current page if written poorly**.

#### Question:

**What is the best strategy to only execute JavaScript that relates directly to the page, while maintaining a single concatenated file?**

#### Current solution that doesn't feel right:

JavaScript related to a specific page is wrapped in a "namespaced" *init* function for that page. Each page is rendered with an inline script calling the init function for that page. It works hunky-dory, but **I would rather not have any inline scripts**.

Does anyone have any clever suggestions? Should I just use an inline script and be done with it? I'm surprised this isn't more of an issue for most developers out there.

Comment: Have you looked into Asynchronously loading your JS?

Comment: **Update:** I've stumbled upon [Lazy Evaluation](http://calendar.perfplanet.com/2011/lazy-evaluation-of-commonjs-modules/) as perhaps the ideal solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use an inline script. If it's one or two lines to initialize the JavaScript you need that's fine. It's actually a good design practice because then it allows re-use of your JavaScript across multiple pages.

Comment: I'm concerned about the obtrusive aspects of this. If my external JavaScript files fail, so does the init call.

Comment: If your external JavaScript fails something is wrong anyway. Usually a debugger still shows you where it actually happened.

Comment: I'm convinced. I will continue with my current practice. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

The advantages of a single (or at least few) concatenated js files are clear (less connections in the page mean lower loading time, you can minify it all at once, ...).

We use such a solution, but: we allow different pages to get different set of concatenated files - though I'm sure there exists different patterns.

In our case we have split javascript files in a few groups by functionality; each page can specify which ones they need. The framework will then deliver the concatenated file with consistent naming and versioning, so that caching works very well on the browser level.

We use django and a home-baked solution - but that's just because we started already a few years ago, when only django-compress was available, and django compress isn't available any more. The [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) successor seems good, but you can find alternatives on [djangopackages/asset-managers](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/asset-managers/).

On different frameworks of course you'll find some equivalent packages. Without a framework, this solution is probably unachievable ;-)

By the way, using these patterns you can also compress your js files (statically, or even dynamically if you have a good caching policy)

Comment: How exactly is this a solution to the problem?

Comment: @MattWolfe well this system still deliver concatenated javascripts, but only javascript that is relevant to the page. So I feel like it is a good solution to the problem. Usually the reason to provide a single concatenated javascript is to optimize page loading (and re-loading). The op does not give more information on the reason behind the question, indeed, so I __might__ be wrong.

Comment: @Stefano My motives to concatenate all JavaScript into one honking are less technical and more political. Personally, I'd take your approach if I could. Nevertheless, if I have to concatenate everything, I'd like to figure a safe way to do it.

Comment: @Matt then you picked the right solution, I just wanted to offer an alternative!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your solution is that bad although it is a good thing that you distrust inline scripts. But you have to find out on what page you are somehow so calling the appropriate init function on each page makes sense. You can also call the init function based on some other factors:

- The page URL
- The page title
- A class set in the document body
- A parameter appended to your script URL and parsed by the global document ready function.

Comment: I hadn't considered the parameter option. While it may not work in this particular case (due to various in-house restrictions), this is one I'm saving for future use. Thanks!

Comment: Oh you can also do it in JavaScript after loading your document. Get the script element, extract the URL and then the parameter e.g. with a Regex.

Answer (score 0):

I simply call a bunch of init functions when the document is ready. Each checks to see if it's needed on the page, if not, simply RETURN.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something as simple as:

```
var locationPath = window.location.pathname;
var locationPage = locationPath.substring(locationPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
switch(locationPage) {
    case 'index.html':
        // do stuff
    break;
    case 'contact.html':
        // do stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really confused exactly why it doesn't feel right to call javascript from the page?  There is a connection between the page and the javascript, and making that explicit should make your code easier to understand, debug, and more organized. I'm sure you could try and use some auto wiring convention but I don't think it really would help you solve the problem. Just call the name spaced function from your page and be done with it..

Comment: Mostly because I'm a great believer in unobtrusive JavaScript. In this case, if the various other JavaScript files **don't** load the init call fails and errors out. Not a great experience for the user, IMO.

Comment: I'm still confused about this though.. If the javascript fails it fails, it doesn't matter if its in a separate file or not.

Comment: Assuming a site has been developed in a progressively enhanced manner, if the external JavaScript **fails to load** (vs. an execution error), the site could still function. If there is a call on the page calling said external code, the user may be left with a JavaScript error. That was my main concern.